# Can I use the toner transfer tecnique to transfer the silk side to the pcb?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I have searched for a while information on how to put the **silk side** on the pcb ( *without using an marker* )

I have made an pcb with the toner transfer technique: *You print with a laser printer over an glossy paper and then use the iron to pass the ink to the pcb on the cooper side, and after attack the cooper with acid* )

Now i'm trying to pass the part that shows how components go on the pcb and they dimensions called the **silk side** on the side of the pcb that doesn't have cooper.

**Question 1:** Will the iron screw the pcb or is it any problems or danger doing this?

**Question 2:** Will the toner ink go off fast ?

**Question 3:** Is there another easy way to do this ? (Again *without a marker* )

Comment: Please include more information on what your doing, its unclear what process you are using.

Comment: Is it better like that ?

Comment: Yep, much better

Comment: Only thing really is to remove the toner from making the PCB before you do the toner silk screen step.  You've already done an iron on step before etching the PCB.  Another session under the iron won't hurt it.  Maybe spray with clear paint to protect the toner silk screen from scratches.

Comment: I've done it, but it doesn't work as well as you're hoping for, unfortunately.  It DOES work, but even the cheapest of chinese boards looks magnitudes better.

Comment: @insta That's not a problem, my problem is that sometimes like today I don't have time to solder all the pieces and now I have to wait 1 week to work on the project again so it's easyer for me ti do this than search the schematic again and start soldering

Comment: Keep all the parts and schematics and layouts (and even the datasheets for the important parts) in a box.  Then you don't have to go looking for them next week when you've got time to work on things again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use toner transfer to apply a silkscreen layer to a PCB. The toner itself is susceptible to removal with solvents, but either a thin layer of conformal coating or use of an [additional substrate](http://www.pcbfx.com/main_site/pages/products/toner_foils.html) will solve this.